# Projections of vectors using dot product

Tags: vectors

I'm working on this maths problem

> If $u=3i+j+k$ and $a=4j−3k$, find the projection of $u$ in the direction of $a$

I know that the formula to calculate the projection of $u$ in the direction of $a$ is

$$\frac{u\dot{}a}{|a|^2}a$$

This is how I go about solving it
$\frac{u\dot{}a}{|a|^2}a=\frac{12+0-3}{16+9}(4j-3k)=\frac{9}{25}(4j-3k)$

However the answers say that it is $\frac{1}{25}(4j-3k)$ and it uses this formula $(u\dot{}\hat{a})\hat{a}$.

Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong and what this formula does? $(u\dot{}\hat{a})\hat{a}$

Comment: $u=3i+j+k$ and $a = 0i + 4j-3k$, then $$u\cdot a = 3(0) + 1(4) + 1(-3) = 1$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 Oh, I see now! Thanks so much. I can't believe I missed something so obvious.

Comment: happens haha! i like the projection formula in below form : $$\dfrac{a\cdot u}{a\cdot a}a$$ It just looks nice aesthetically :D